# Blogger: Layout problem when searching by label

Tags: blogger

I am having an issue with this blog: [www.bargainbuggyblog.com](http://www.bargainbuggyblog.com)

I have it set up with links at the top. When you click on "take a peek" (search label-peek) it causes my right sidebar to move off the outer wrapper portion of the blog and into the background space.  
The "deals" tab at the top is set up the same way, but is not causing this issue.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: doctype.com might be a better place to ask this?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't figured out exactly what the problem is, but I noticed that the `div` tags are not balanced.  (There are more opening tags than closing tags.)  If I remove one of the `</div>` end tags after "Savings 100.24", it fixes the right side-bar.  This isn't the correct solution (the footer is still incorrect), but maybe it will help point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks- I'll dig a little deeper and see what I find.  :)